Celery worker inspect ping not working - remote control required?
I have some Celery workers up and running, which use RabbitMQ as message broker. Everything works find and tasks are being processed.
I would like to be able to check if those workers are healthy. I am spending already some days on it and one of the commands for that would be celery -A app inspect ping. But all I get is No nodes replied within time constraint
I also increased the timeout, but I get the same message.
I started to dig deeper and started to wonder if Remote control is required for that, since my app has it currently set to false:
celery_app.conf.update(worker_enable_remote_control=False)

I made a test, where I set it to True and I get an answer while running the ping command.
I set it to false, since I am not sure yet based on the security implications, since remote control seems rather powerful, with being able to purge queues and what not.
Happy to hear if there is another way to make the ping work or what the best practice would be.
